# Organizar XML's de layout nos resources (res) do projeto Android

Tags: android, organização-de-projeto

**Problema**

Meu projeto está crescendo e com ele, a quantidade de arquivos na pasta layout, e já está se tornando um tanto quanto difícil encontrar um arquivo especifico, já que eles não estão agrupados de nenhuma forma, somente em ordem alfabética.

Então tentei criar subpastas para layout, para separa-los por sessões, por exemplo:

```
layout
-- layout_grid
   -- grid_detail.xml
   -- grid_item.xml
--layout_form
   -- form1.xml
   -- form2.xml
```

Mas isso parece não ser suportado, pelo Android, já que os `xml's`, não são mais encontrados.

**Perguntas**

1. Gostaria de saber se é possível de alguma forma criar subpastas para
   layout?
2. Se a resposta da pergunta anterior for **Não**, então se há alguma
       outra boa prática para organizar a pasta de layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Infelizmente, realmente a resposta é não (a princípio).

O Android não suporta subpastas neste caso - aceita somente arquivos dentro de pastas pré-definidas. O que já vi diversas vezes, é nomear os arquivos com um prefixo, como se separasse pelos pacotes do aplicativo, como por exemplo "usuario_", "venda_", etc...

**Porém**, é possível fazer utilizar subpastas com o auxílio do Gradle, configurando o mesmo para reconhecer as subpastas que você criou. Você pode ver um exemplo [aqui](https://github.com/eskimoapps/ResourceNestingExample).

Comment: Muito boa, sua indicação, talvez implementarei o 1° caso dos prefixos, parece ser mais simples, do que o outro, mais sendo valido para observação futura.

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade há sim um modo de organizar os resources por meio de subpastas.

No arquivo gradle (nível app), precisará usar a tag **sourceSets**:

```
sourceSets {
main {
   res.srcDirs = [
      'src/main/res',
      'src/main/res2'
   ]
}
```

Sendo assim, o projeto conterá duas pastas 'resources', **res** e **res2**, e dentro de cada uma haverá a estrutura usual, com as pastas *drawable*, *layout*, *values* e assim por diante.

Para ver um exemplo melhor veja este site: [Organizar pasta Res](http://www.orogersilva.com/estrutura-de-projeto-android-o-modo-alternativo/).

Answer (score 2):

Eu organizo assim:

1. Se o layout é referente a um `Activity`, então o nome será `activity_nome_da_classe`
2. Se o layout é referente a um `Fragment`, então o nome será `fragment_nome_da_classe`
3. Se o layout é referente a um item de `ListView`, então o nome será `list_item_nome_da_classe`

E assim por diante... Acho que deu para entender né? É uma sugestão apenas.